# Image being set from Bitmaps is making the rest of the layout slow?

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview

I have an ImageView's image being set from a Bitmap from the Gallery. But when I actually have it set. It seems to slow the rest of the functions like entering text in the EditText fields. Is this because of the image being used and if so would using Picasso help? Or is it the layout of the XML and the image being pushed up thanks to the Phone's Keyboard? I know you can reduce the size of the actual Bitmap to be set but I would actually like to know if this might be the case. Thank you!

Comment: `I know you can reduce the size of the actual Bitmap to be set but I would actually like to know if this might be the case.`. Please try. And report.

Comment: I know you can scale down the image to reduce the memory being used. But It makes the image either blurry or but fat on the y axis. Is there a way to actually reduce the size when setting the bitmap?

Comment: Please tell original resolution and the resolution you scaled it down to. It does not have to become blurry or whatever. Also tell the dimensions of the image view.

Comment: `Is there a way to actually reduce the size when setting the bitmap?`Yes. Scale it down. You already know that.